# build a drop down list like android applications' menu jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to build a drop down menu/list like the menu of the applications in android.

In android you swipe the menu up to open the applications' menu

something like this

[image: swipe menu]

How can I build one like that using jquery?

Comment: I removed the android tag as it has nothing to do with android, just the example.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking and found this:

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/sliding-top-menu-with-jquery/

Is this close to what you need?

Comment: ya it's close but but not exactly  , i wanted some thing to swipe up and down to open and close , Thanks alot ;)

Comment: Wouldn't it then be easy to just change the button click to a rollover instead?  Anyway, that's not exactly what I wanted either.  I think I will use something more like this: http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-showhide-div/  Good Luck!